# robot_pose_ekf is there a way to override the tf base_footprint

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Robot-pose-ekf it publishes a tf :odom_combined → base_footprint. I would like to change it to base_link. How is this best done rather then adding a base_footprint to my urdf.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111526/robot_pose_ekf--is-there-a-way-to-override-the-tf-base_footprint/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added the base_footprint and static tf to base_link. This seemed to be the easiest solution that works.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2014-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0